# Button background color on touch event is not the same as on the click event

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, touch

I am trying to make button change color back to red after each click (desktop devices) or touch event (smart phones).

[Here working example from codepen](http://codepen.io/FrenkyB/pen/XKOpEK)

Code:

```
$(
  function(){    
    $("#btnAdd").mouseenter(function () {
          jQuery("#btnAdd").css("background-color", "black");
      }).mouseleave(function () {
          jQuery("#btnAdd").css("background-color", "#d80000");
      });    
  }  
);
```

It works fine for the click event. But, it doesnt' work for the touch event. Color stays black. How can I simulate 'mouseleave' event on the phone? It seems that only 'mouseenter' event is triggered, because color is changed to black and it stays black, until some other element is clicked.

I've also tried mousedown and mouseup events, but end result was similiar. On a desktop all fine, on smartphone color stayed black.

Comment: And when you would use onclick event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add both mousedown and touchstart events in your code using the on() method.

```
$(function() {
  $("#btnAdd").on('mousedown touchstart', function () {
    jQuery("#btnAdd").css("background-color", "black");
  }).on('mouseup touchend', function() {
    jQuery("#btnAdd").css("background-color", "red");
  }); 
});
```

Here's the working example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JKxEBJ

---

Aside, why don't you use CSS :active to achieve this effect?

Comment: If you wonder how would it look like by using CSS :active. Take a look at this example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QEYdkL

Answer (score 1):

Please try it with onclick instead.

You can try using `$("button").click(function() {});`

Comment: Yes but how can I make button black - red ? LIke it is on a desktop - when hovering is black, after click is red.

Comment: You could use :hover, :click CSS attributes  @FrenkyB

Answer (score 1):

You can use the touch events for smart phones.

```
$("#btnAdd").bind('touchstart ', function(){
      jQuery("#btnAdd").css("background-color", "black");
    });
```

Here is the [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wcf3go2f/1/) link

And FYI, there are several events to detect the touch in smart phones, especially for IOS.

1. TouchStart
2. TouchMove
3. TouchEnd
4. TouchCancel

Hope it helps you :)